# How to use open graph in facebook APP page

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a facebook app, in which I am opening my website's pages. I want to use open graph in this app. what I mean is this:
user can see all pages and can post as a open graph. When any user's click on ticker link on facebook, it should open into my facebook app. (similar like social reader app).
Please tell me is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fandjango for authentication and facepy for graph api.

Answer (score 3):

Use [fandjango](https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango) to deal with the authentication for your canvas app and then use [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy) (by the same developer) for interacting with the Graph API

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am doing same thing, but when I use fandjango and facepy, I am not able to post as a open graph object.